# WSO2 API Manager - API Usage statistics by each user is missing in latest release 2.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I am using WSO2 API Manager 2.0.0 along with WSO2 DAS 3.0.1

Query : API Usage statistics in PUBLISHER STATISTICS does not have user-wise split in latest version. Based on the documentation and webinars of WSO2, looks like user-wise split for API usage statistics was available in earlier versions. Am i missing any configurations here? Please clarify.

Comment: what do you mean by a user? a publisher user or a client user?

Comment: By user-wise split, I meant client-user here who consumes the API. The publisher will be able to see how the API's are consumed like how many API calls made by each user for the selected time-period(day, week, month)

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to APIM 1.10, then AFAIK there is no major difference in statistic bases in APIM 1.10 and 2.0. The statistics module in both versions is able to show publisher wise user statistics. For that you can use [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Viewing+API+Statistics#ViewingAPIStatistics-APIPublisherstatistics) guide.As in the documentation you can check the user statistics by clicking on the API and referring to its Users tab.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I have gone through the documentation.
In APIM 2.0.0, is there a way to generate API Usage statistics report with user-wise, time-wise split available?